# Why is apt purge trying to install my packages?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I am using Lubuntu 16.04 which is Ubuntu + LXDE. I am running the command `sudo apt purge /path/to/files/*.deb` and instead of removing all of the packages in that directory, I just get `filename.deb is already the newest version (5.2.1-2)` for every package in the directory. I feel like I've tried every combination of apt, apt-get, and dpkg and the words purge and remove. `apt-cache rdepends` says that there are no dependent packages.

Why can't I remove my packages?

Comment: apt might be confused because you're passing all the debs to one apt command. Try purging one package at a time?

Comment: @HoD even independent requests returned the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages were installed with independent package names that were different than the .deb files.

`dpkg --list | grep packagename | awk {'print $2'}` showed me which packages to remove.

`apt purge` worked fine after that.